# Агрегация данных по дате

Tags: sql, ms-access

Есть 2 таблицы : `tblCostOfMin` и `tblViolations`

tblCostOfMin

```
Код   Cost     Date          Dept
1     23.20    24.04.2019    OS
2     388.80   24.04.2019    OL
3     27.80    28.04.2019    OS
4     488.80   28.04.2019    OL
```

tblViolations

```
Код  vDate        EmpName         Violations    Time
1    24.04.2019   Имя Фамилия     Нарушение     9
2    25.04.2019   Имя2 Фамилия2   Нарушение2    7
3    29.04.2019   Имя Фамилия     Нарушение     5
4    29.04.2019   Имя2 Фамилия2   Нарушение3    2
```

Никак не могу выбрать из этих таблиц данные в формате: Стоимость (`cost`) * Время (`time`), по условию, что нарушение произошло в период действия стоимости.

Comment: _в период действия_ это когда даты совпадают?

Comment: *по условию, что нарушение произошло в период действия стоимости.* Я вижу даты, и не вижу никаких периодов. А также не вижу никаких данных в tblViolations, которые позволят определить, с каким типом (Dept ?) из tblCostOfMin следует их соотносить.

Comment: нет, когда дата нарушения <= дате установления стоимости и > даты предыдущего установления стоимости

Comment: период появляются в таблице tblCosOfMin, это периоды между записями с одним Dept. Например, для Dept = OS, будет три периода до 24.04.2019 с 24.042019 до 28.04.2019 и с 28.04.2019 до установления новой цены

Comment: Это ожидаемо. А вот теперь расскажите, как определить, по шкале какого Dept надо категорировать отдельно взятое нарушение. Я таких данных в tblViolations не наблюдаю.

Comment: Вы правы, этот момент я опустил. Есть третья таблица с с соотношением EmpName  к Dept, называется tblEmp